# Installing aws-sdk in node js returns npm error

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install the aws-sdk as per the instructions in getting started using AWS Polly service with node.js.  I have tried to install it as instructed in windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 machine and in a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. In all attempts the install fails.  The command I used is 'npm install aws-sdk' on Windows and RPi.

Here is the output from the install on the Raspberry Pi and under Visual Studio:

```
Registry url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
Current Time: 8/6/2017 1:16:59 AM
Last Refreshed: 2/20/2016 1:36:30 PM
Number of Results: 257342
====Executing command 'npm install aws-sdk --save '====

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "aws-sdk" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file C:\Users\barry\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\isarray\1.0.0\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\barry\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\isarray\1.0.0\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\barry\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AWS_Proxy\AWS_Proxy_app\npm-debug.log
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `-g` flag?